# What's the difference between Mockito Matchers isA, any, eq, and same?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, difference, matcher

I am confused on what's the difference between them, and which one to choose in which case. Some difference might be obvious, like `any` and `eq`, but I'm including them all just to be sure.

I wonder about their differences because I came across this problem:
I have this POST method in a Controller class

```
public Response doSomething(@ResponseBody Request request) {
    return someService.doSomething(request);
}
```

And would like to perform a unit test on that controller.
I have two versions. The first one is the simple one, like this

```
@Test
public void testDoSomething() {
    //initialize ObjectMapper mapper
    //initialize Request req and Response res
    
    when(someServiceMock.doSomething(req)).thenReturn(res);

    Response actualRes = someController.doSomething(req);
    assertThat(actualRes, is(res));
}
```

But I wanted to use a MockMvc approach, like this one

```
@Test
public void testDoSomething() {
    //initialize ObjectMapper mapper
    //initialize Request req and Response res
    
    when(someServiceMock.doSomething(any(Request.class))).thenReturn(res);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/do/something")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(req))
    )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$message", is("done")));
}
```

Both work well. But I wanted my `someServiceMock.doSomething()` in the MockMvc approach to receive `req`, or at least an object that has the same variable values as `req` (not just any `Request` class), and return `res`, just like the first. I know that it's impossible using the MockMvc approach (or is it?), because the object passed in the actual call is always different from the object passed in the mock. Is there anyway I can achieve that? Or does it even make sense to do that? Or should I be satisfied using `any(Request.class)`? I've tried `eq`, `same`, but all of them fail.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

- [`any()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any--) checks absolutely nothing. Since Mockito 2.0, [`any(T.class)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-) shares `isA` semantics to mean "any `T`" or properly "any instance of type `T`".

  [This is a change compared to Mockito 1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/55631479), where [`any(T.class)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html) checked absolutely nothing but saved a cast prior to Java 8: "Any kind object, not necessary of the given class. The class argument is provided only to avoid casting."
- [`isA(T.class)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#isA-java.lang.Class-) checks that the argument `instanceof T`, implying it is non-null.
- [`same(obj)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#same-T-) checks that the argument refers to the same instance as `obj`, such that `arg == obj` is true.
- [`eq(obj)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#eq-T-) checks that the argument equals `obj` according to its `equals` method. This is also the behavior if you pass in real values without using matchers.

  Note that unless `equals` is overridden, you'll see the default Object.equals implementation, which would have the same behavior as `same(obj)`.

If you need more exact customization, you can use an adapter for your own predicate:

- For Mockito 1.x, use [`argThat`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html) with a custom Hamcrest `Matcher<T>` that selects exactly the objects you need.
- For Mockito 2.0 and beyond, use [`Matchers.argThat`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#argThat-org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher-) with a custom `org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher<T>`, or [`MockitoHamcrest.argThat`](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/hamcrest/MockitoHamcrest.html#argThat(org.hamcrest.Matcher)) with a custom Hamcrest `Matcher<T>`.

You may also use [`refEq`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#refEq-T-java.lang.String...-), which uses *reflection* to confirm object equality; Hamcrest has a similar implementation with [SamePropertyValuesAs](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/beans/SamePropertyValuesAs.html) for public bean-style properties. Note that on GitHub [issue #1800 proposes deprecating and removing `refEq`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1800), and as in that issue you might prefer `eq` to better give your classes better encapsulation over their sense of equality.

Comment: This is a practical answer: not only differentiating Mockito's 4 _argument matchers_ but also hinting **risks** with `equals` and **customization** with `argThat` 

Comment: Please add `refEq()` This matcher can be used when equals() is not implemented on compared objects. Matcher uses java reflection API to compare fields of wanted and actual object.

Comment: @Ivan Though it wasn't in the original question, I've added a mention of `refEq`, including [the proposal to deprecate and remove it from Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1800).

Comment: So, what should we use for the latest version?

Comment: @Robert The list above tells you the semantic difference between them. You'll have to match them to your use case.

Answer (score 3):

If your Request.class implements equals, then you can use eq():

```
Bar bar = getBar();
when(fooService.fooFxn(eq(bar)).then...
```

The above *when* would activate on

```
fooService.fooFxn(otherBar);
```

if

```
otherBar.equals(bar);
```

Alternatively, if you want to the mock to work for some other subset of input (for instance, all Bars with Bar.getBarLength()>10), you could create a Matcher. I don't see this pattern too often, so usually I create the Matcher as a private class:

```
private static class BarMatcher extends BaseMatcher<Bar>{
...//constructors, descriptions, etc.
  public boolean matches(Object otherBar){
     //Checks, casts, etc.
     return otherBar.getBarLength()>10;
  }
}
```

You would then use this matcher as follows:

```
when(fooService.fooFxn(argThat(new BarMatcher())).then...
```

Hope that helps!