# Matcher vs Object.equal?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

What's the purpose of Custom Matcher and how we can compare with

```
Object.equal().
```

I have a problem that `Object.equal()` solve easily while passing parameters in `when()` but some time I need to use Matchers. I need to know what would be the behavior and how it would be executed.

My current code is:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
  when(service.foo(xyzService, new ARequest(1, "A"))).thenReturn(new AResponse(1, "passed"));
  when(service.foo(xyzService, new ARequest(2, "2A"))).thenReturn(new AResponse(2, "passed"));
  when(service.foo(xyzService, new BRequest(1, "B"))).thenReturn(new BResponse(112, "passed"));

  c.execute();
}
```

currently it works fine but in my actual business case i am not able to mock `xyzService` it a method level variable. I want o use `any()`  instead of `xyzService`. but in this case everything brokers.

Comment: Show the code..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Mockito Matchers isA, any, eq, and same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890011/whats-the-difference-between-mockito-matchers-isa-any-eq-and-same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `when`, you train the mock method either on fixed parameters or on matchers. We can't mix. If you want to use the `any()` matcher for one parameter, you have to convert the other param to a matcher too:

```
when(service.foo(any(), eq(new ARequest(1, "A")))).thenReturn(new AResponse(1, "passed"));
```

If this doesn't work for your test case, then either the `equals` implemention in `ARequest` is broken or the test or the test object (i.e.: the expected method call with any service and this request never happens in the tested code)

Answer (score 1):

Matchers are typically not needed except in complex object structures or if you want to base equality on different criteria then what the objects equal method has defined.

**Equality Example**

For instance, take this simplified example (pseudo code):

```
class test {
   int x,y,z;

   bool equals() {
     return x == y && x == z && y == z
   }
 // should override hashCode as well

}
```

But then in your test you only cared about x and z matching you could write a matcher to perform this validation. For the given example, obviously it doesn't make sense because the comparison is so basic.

**Complex Objects**

I have created generic matchers in the past that can crawl a whole object graph performing a field by field comparison. They *could* also be used to  perform different 'matching' criteria based on context. I say *could* because this generally breaks the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html).