# Mockito not returning correct result from mocked method with multiple "when" conditions

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have a simple DTO class:

```java
@Data // lombok
public class MyObj {
    private int id;
    private String someProperty;
}
```

and a class with some computation logic for the DTO object:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public String doSomething(MyObj obj) {
        // some calculations
    }
}
```

I tried to mock `MyClass` to use it in some unit tests, but encountered a weird problem. Therefore, I created this minimal test code to illustrate the issue:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    private final MyObj myObjFirst = new MyObj();
    private final MyObj myObjSecond = new MyObj();

    @Mock
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        doReturn("OTHER")
                .when(myClass)
                .doSomething(any(MyObj.class));
        doReturn("FIRST")
                .when(myClass)
                .doSomething(myObjFirst);
        doReturn("SECOND")
                .when(myClass)
                .doSomething(myObjSecond);
    }

    @Test
    public void doSomething() {
        assertEquals("FIRST", myClass.doSomething(myObjFirst)); // fail, actual value "SECOND"
        assertEquals("SECOND", myClass.doSomething(myObjSecond));
        assertEquals("OTHER", myClass.doSomething(new MyObj()));
        assertEquals("OTHER", myClass.doSomething(new MyObj()));
    }
}
```

For some reason, `myClass.doSomething(myObjFirst)` produces the string `"SECOND"` instead of the expected `"FIRST"`, therefore the test fails at the first assert.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

When stubbing, wrap the expected objects into `Mockito.same` to match them by reference ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30898813/2237467) for different matchers):

```java
@Before
public void setUp() {
    doReturn("OTHER")
            .when(myClass)
            .doSomething(any(MyObj.class));
    doReturn("FIRST")
            .when(myClass)
            .doSomething(same(myObjFirst)); // <-- HERE
    doReturn("SECOND")
            .when(myClass)
            .doSomething(same(myObjSecond)); // <-- AND HERE
}
```

### Explanation

Mockito seems to use the `equals` method to detect the given argument to the mocked method (reference to docs needed).

Due to [Lombok's `@Data` annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data), a `MyObj.equals` implementation is generated, which compares the objects by their fields `id` and `someProperty`. Because both fields are `null` on `myObjFirst` and `myObjSecond`, and because [last stubbing has the highest importance](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data), Lombok first compares the argument given to `myClass.doSomething` against `myObjSecond`, immediately finding a match and returning `"SECOND"`.

If Lombok's `@Data` annotation was omitted from `MyObj`, the above code would work as-is, because then `MyObj.equals` method would default to object reference comparison, making `myObjFirst` not equal to `myObjSecond`.

In this case, however, `myObjFirst` equals `myObjSecond` equals `new MyObj()`, unless their properties are set to different values.