# Return different values from mock, depending on args

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to make mock that should return different value if the argument had concrete class. I created tableVerificationService mock object and created these when conditions.

```
Mockito.when(tableVerificationService.verify(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(true);
Mockito.when(tableVerificationService.verify(Mockito.any(DTable.class))).thenReturn(false);
```

But now it returns false in any case, even if i pass another from DTable object.

If i change order of these two lines, it will return true in all cases. Is there any way to make correct behavior?

Comment: Which version of Mockito are you using? Mockito 1.x would have the behavior you describe and would require `isA`, but Mockito 2.0+ this should work as you have it. See: [What's the difference between Mockito Matchers isA, any, eq, and same?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30890011/1426891)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.thenAnswer()` or `.then()` (shorter) to have more control of the returned value.

An example might visualize this better.

Let's assume we want to mock the Java class:

```
public class OtherService {

  public String doStuff(String a) {
    return a;
  }
}
```

... and we want to return "even" if the passed `String` is even and "uneven" otherwise.

By using `.then()` we get access to the `InvocationOnMock` and can access the passed argument. This helps to determine the returned value:

```
class MockitoExampleTest {

  @Test
  void testMe() {

    OtherService otherService = Mockito.mock(OtherService.class);

    when(otherService.doStuff(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).then(invocationOnMock -> {
      String passedString = invocationOnMock.getArgument(0);

      if (passedString.length() % 2 == 0) {
        return "even";
      } else {
        return "uneven";
      }
    });

    System.out.println(otherService.doStuff("duke")); // even
    System.out.println(otherService.doStuff("egg")); // uneven

  }
}
```

With this technique you can check the passed argument and determine if it's your concrete class and then return whatever value you want.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that is very useful and flexible approach. But in my case Mockito.isA was enough to determine the class of the argument.